# C# 'ref' keyword equivalent or workaround in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

If I have a object:

```
var Edge = function() {
  this.a = 0;
  this.b = 0;
  this.prevEdge = null;
  this.nextEdge = null;
  // +20 other members
}
```

and a function:

```
function ProcessEdge(e)
{
  // some processing and then
  e = e.nextEdge;
  // some processing and then return something
}
```

which is called from other function this way:

```
var e = new Edge();
// some processing and then
var res = ProcessEdge(e);
// e should be now the same object as e.nextEdge
// but it is not, e is still e
```

The `e` should be now `e.nextEdge`, but it is still `e`, because `e = e.nextEdge;` in `ProcessEdge()` function breaks the reference.

The first thought was to achieve member equality by assigning every member one by one in `ProcessEdge()` function using something like `e.a = e.nextEdge.a; e.b = e.nextEdge.b; e.prevEdge = e.nextEdge.prevEdge; e.nextEdge = e.nextEdge.nextEdge;`, but the reference is still broken. When I do this way, I also must compare member by member, and the spaghetti code and it's slowness comes to picture.

In C# and similar languages the reference retaining could be achieved simply by using `ref` keyword before the variable name and the reference is retained and the speed and the simpliness and speed is as expected.

Okay, now the method which works (this is the one I have used so far):

```
function ProcessEdge(e)
{
  // some processing and then
  e.Value = e.Value.nextEdge; // instead of e = e.nextEdge;
  // some processing and then return something
}

// And the calling part:
var e = new Edge();
// some processing and then
var res = (function ()
{
  e = { Value: e };
  var $res = ProcessEdge(e);
  e = e.Value;
  return $res;
})
.call(this);
```

This method works fine, but the problem is the inline function, which (AFAIK) is created every time the row `var res = (function() {}...` is executed. This `var res...` is inside loop which is called very very many times, in some cases 100,000 - 500,000 times per second, if there are a lot of data.

**So, is there a faster way to achieve the reference retaining?**

---

EDIT:

According to comments below, I made a speed tests:
http://jsperf.com/closure-vs-compund
http://jsperf.com/closure-vs-compund/2

The result was that above mentioned closure method is very slow, as I expected. I found that fastest way was to drop the function `ProcessEdge()` all the way and instead inline it. The speed of closure method was 26.63 % of the speed of the fastest one. So the inline method was 3.7 times faster than closure method. The inline method is as follows:

```
function main10(a)
{
  var res=0, res2, e, b;
  for (var i=0;i<10000;i++)
  {
    e = new Edge();
    b = new Edge();
    b.a = i*a;

    e.nextEdge = b;

    // ProcessEdge() as inline version:
    e = e.nextEdge;
    res += e.a-10;

    if (e!=b) res+=1000;
  }
  return res;
}
```

But usually we need to use functions (and give the interpreter a chance for automatic inlining, if ever). The next fastest was to use "global" reference. The speed was 98.45 % of the fastest.

The `global_val` is a holder for return value (it is used because function in Javascript cannot return more than one value). This means that we have outside any loops and just one step above in scope hierachy a reference object `global_val`, which is created the same time when all other functions are created. The `ProcessEdge()` function overwrites the value of `global_val`, and because `e.nextEdge` is object, this means only light and fast overwrite of reference (no new copy). `e = e.nextEdge` causes reference breakage, but it is irrelevant, because the reference is now in `global_val` and we are safe.

In `main11()` function we call ProcessEdge() this way: `res += ProcessEdge11(e)` and store the reference from global_val to e this way: `e = global_val`.

```
var global_val = {};
function ProcessEdge11(e)
{
  e = e.nextEdge;
  global_val = e;
  return e.a-10;
}

function main11(a)
{
  var res=0, res2, e, b;
  for (var i=0;i<10000;i++)
  {
    e = new Edge();
    b = new Edge();
    b.a = i*a;
    e.nextEdge = b;

    // some processing and then
    res += ProcessEdge11(e);
    e = global_val;
    if (e!=b) res+=1000;  
  }  
  return res;
}
```

Then there is still one more method which is wise to mention: using `function inside function`. It is slower (84.42 % of the fastest) than the above two methods, but rather simple. It basically relies to the same fact than the one that uses `global_val`: function has access to it's parent scopes variables (objects) in a way that doesn't break the reference, because no local vars are created and the function handles variables one scope up. The essential note is that the variable is not "passed in" and that there are no such local assignments that would break the reference.

```
function main8(a)
{
  var pseudo_global_ret = 0;

  var res=0, res2, e, b;
  for (var i=0;i<10000;i++)
  {
    e = new Edge();
    b = new Edge();
    b.a = i*a;

     e.nextEdge = b;

    _ProcessEdge();
    res += pseudo_global_ret;
    if (e!=b) res+=1000;
  }
  return res;

  function _ProcessEdge()
  {
    e = e.nextEdge;
    pseudo_global_ret = e.a-10; // instead of return e.a-10
  }
}
```

And one note more: Javascript version of swap function is a little different than in C# where is the `ref` keyword. In C# we could call `swap(ref a, ref b)`, but in Javascript this is not possible. The way to go is:

```
function swap()
{
  var tmp=a;
  a=b;
  b=tmp;
}
var a={x:0}
var b={x:1}
swap();
```

If trying some sort of `swap(a,b)`, the reference breaks. Of course this is essential to wrap inside closure to prevent pollution of global scope.

If someone finds faster way to reference retaining, please answer to this question.

Comment: No. There is *no* Call by Reference support in JavaScript. Mutating objects is acceptable, as shown and works because of [Call by Object Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing). However, I would suggest trying to change the code to use the return value (possibly compound) if possible.

Comment: @pst: Could you provide an example of the method you suggest (returning compound value)?

Comment: `return {a: 1, b: 2}`. Only one value can be returned in JavaScript, but it can be composite/compounded.

Comment: Is that faster than my `(function(){...})
.call(this)`?

Comment: You'll have to run performance tests in your *particular* environment/code. ECMAScript implementation performance can vary greatly. V8 is generally *very efficient* at handling objects like that, but YMMV as to which approach is faster/"better".